How exactly do you expand your knowledge about your research field as a PhD student?
My research field is functional analysis, and currently, I am acquiring new knowledge simply "by chance". This means, I need something specific to know, so I educate myself on it, and continue my work. Although this might work, I don't find that it's the ideal way to do it.
The problem I encounter is that if my advisor and I stumble across a problem to solve, I am simply unprepared from a knowledge point of view speaking. I understand the problem, but I do not know how to solve it - or at least how to tackle it, what kind of ideas are worth investigating. So I always end up relying on my basic knowledge from my Bachelor's and Master's studies, instead of more professional and fine tuned knowledge. Eventually, my advisor comes up with a solution and once I understand it I can investigate it further.
In other words, I simply lack the necessary knowledge to not only find potential solutions to our mathematical problems, but also to realize when something needs to be mathematically corrected or fine tuned. This is also something which goes completely off my radar.
Now the problem is that there is just such an overwhelming amount of books on functional analysis and operator theory, that I don't know how and where to start. Should I create some schedule and simply work through those textbooks? How can I do it efficiently?
One might suggest to go visit seminars, but the problem is that there is exactly one seminar a week in the city I study where actually topics about strictly only functional analysis or operator theory are being presented. So I don't know whether there are online seminars which I might potentially check out?

This question is similar to: How to improve self-learning as a PhD student?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Welcome to the site. There are existing questions on self-learning. I encourage you to take the site's tour and browse through other questions.

@RichardErickson It's not the same question. My problem is that I do have the resources, but I don't know how to start. The only resources I have are textbooks, and I have them available. Seminars, as I said, there is only one seminar a week, and there are no extra courses I could take at my university in my topic. So I can only rely on textbooks. But there are so many, that I simply don't know where and how to start, and how I should effectively go through them. It's not a problem of "how to gather the material to study", but rather "I have the material to study, but how should I start?"

I am a tenured math professor, and every couple months I find out there is something very basic in one of the areas I work in that I didn't know that I feel like I should've known.  You'll never learn everything relevant to what you're working on.  If you're clever enough, you figure it out from scratch for yourself, look around now that you know what you're looking for, and find out (or have pointed out by a reviewer) that it's something that's been done.  Just give up on knowing everything and solve the problems you can with what you know.

If you knew how to solve the problem from general knowledge, chances are that someone else also could solve the problem from general knowledge, and it'd be solved already.  Most problems you come across, or even work on, you won't solve.  That's how math research works.

@S-F Perhaps How to stop hopping the learning chain and actually begin somewhere? is more relevant.

From the question I find it difficult to get a clear picture your current state of knowledge and the state of knowledge that you would like to have - after all, nobody knows all of functional analysis and operator theory. Questions: (1) How far are you into your PhD (in terms of months or years)? (2) How much have you learnt in your Bachelor's and Master's programme about functional analysis and operator theory (how many course and which courses)? (3) Can you give a concrete example of a piece of knowledge that you did not have at a point when your advisor used it to solve a problem?

(I'm aware that my questions are rather specific for this site - but I'm trying to understand whether your issue is really a lack of knowledge or unrealisitic assumptions on how much one can know at a certain point.)

@JochenGlueck (1) 2nd (2) Actually not that much, because my university specializes more in applied mathematics. I only had one functional analysis course (which covered the most basic things) and one operator theory course (which covered the fundamentals of operators). The rest I've learned by writing my Master's thesis about functional analysis and now being a PhD student (and also attending seminars), so I keep learning new stuff everyday. Mostly my knowledge in this area is self-learned.

@JochenGlueck (3) We needed something from O. Bekkens' PhD thesis but instead of asking UCLA for a copy we recreated it on our own. This was only possible because my advisor simply has been reading lots of papers for the past decades, and he knew one Japanese paper from the 1970s which eventually helped us recreate what we needed. I would've never found it, let alone came up with that solution.

‘I don't find that it's the ideal way to do it.’ Learning at the research level is like that. How would you prefer things to be?

Typically, one works with an advisor who can point you to resources. If your advisor can't do that then it can be very difficult. If you can meet frequently and ask questions, perhaps you can get pointed toward useful resources, but only if they work to keep current.
Seminars will help, but only if you interact with people and make it active rather than passive attendance. Conferences are a good place to make contacts and start discussions that can continue afterward. You might be able to ask a senior member for a suggestion of a paper that you promise to present in the future. Now you have an active task.
Note that textbooks are unlikely to get you to the research edge in almost every field. Very unlikely. That isn't their purpose and things change rapidly in active fields.
Recent papers are probably essential for you. A good research librarian can help, as can the internet. Recent books may be better than older ones, provided they contain modern methods. Preprint servers might contain a lot of what you need, but not everything there will be sufficiently vetted, so you need to judge.
The typical process with recent papers is that if/when you find them hard to follow, go to papers they cite first and try to understand them. This was the common process in pre-internet days. Lots of hours in the library with lots of journals to consult. If you are somewhat isolated this might be the only way. A research librarian can probably get access to most things. Such librarians often have (international) circles of contact with other librarians.
Some traditional methods in established fields may be enough, but not in new or rapidly evolving fields.

My advisor gave me some essential literature, but I just don't really know what I'm supposed to do with it - study it like a student, or treat it like some sort of encyclopedia so I can always look up important stuff there? Seminars, conferences: There aren't many (in my area) for functional analysis, almost none. The same goes for research papers in my particular topic and problem I'm working on. The latest is 27 years old, and the textbooks and other papers we're working with are from the 1970s usually.

Yes, study it like a student. You need to understand it to gain insight. And, you are unlikely to find things very specific to your problem. If you did, then your problem has probably been solved by others. Insight. How do things work? Why do the work? When don't they work?

Why are you working on problems that have been untouched for 30 years?  (Sometimes there is a good reason, but usually there are good reasons no one has worked on these things for a while!)

@AlexanderWoo Because my Professor and the author who wrote last about these problems 30 years ago are good friends, so that's how we got the idea to work on it again.

First of all, are you sure that a lack of knowledge is the issue? When you try to analyse how your supervisor solved it in the end, is about them knowing stuff at the beginning of the process that you don't? Or is it more about tenacity, in that they kept trying to actually solve the problem while you were scared off by not knowing how? Figuring out a new proof usually involves feeling very, very lost, and in my experience novice researchers often struggle comitting to really try.
When it comes to actual knowledge, I think it is useful to distinguish the fundamentals of your own field and other stuff that might be useful. The fundamentals of your field are something you really want actively present in your mind. If you are missing stuff here, a detailed reading of a textbook or following some online course plus doing exercises might help. Check in with your supervisor to figure out if you are missing something here.
For more peripheral stuff, it suffices to recall enough of it to identify that it might help in a particular setting, and to be able to quickly look it up and ascertain if it does. It is impossible to learn everything in the "might be useful" category, and here I think we just collect stuff over the decades. The strategy here is be curious and patient.

"is about them knowing stuff at the beginning of the process that you don't?" Exactly. He knows so much more stuff than me, and when he proposes a solution I first have to educate myself on the new stuff introduced by him in the solution. I do have the fundamental knowledge of my field. It's just that the knowledge my advisor uses for coming up with new solutions is just very, very specific.


Why is your advisor working on your problems?  2) Why are you working on problems that seem to be solvable only by finding the right piece of knowledge in a vast body of knowledge that you can't have learned?  3) I'm still skeptical that the problem is a lack of knowledge - it's quite common especially for grad students to spend lots of time rediscovering things before finding them in the literature.  4) Is the new stuff introduced by him actually in the literature, or is it something that he just came up with, and maybe you should start learning to just come up with also?



We're working on those problems together, we're both listed as authors. I am just talking about some points in our problems which need very specialized knowledge. 2) Isn't that the usual way when you're a PhD student? 4) Not in the literature. The literature itself covers the basics, which I do know and understand. The knowledge I'm referring to are in papers which at first glance might seem totally unrelated to our problem but it turns out that they are the answer to our problems. So it's very, very specific knowledge you only get after decades of reading lots of papers



Maybe I'm old-fashioned, but I think a math PhD student should have their own problems.  2) No - PhD students should be steered towards problems that are good for PhD students, which means requiring more in the way of time trying stuff and less in the way of extensive knowledge of what's been done.  4) "Literature" includes published papers.

